# Why is Docker daemon API listening on //./pipe/docker_engine_windows when docker ps expects and fails to open open //./pipe/docker_engine

Tags: docker, docker-daemon

TLDR: Title, and:
**Is this a problem, or am I looking in the wrong place?**

I'm trying to understand our build agent which is a Windows Server 2019 Standard,

```
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker> (Get-WmiObject -class
Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard
```

(For fun reasons I only have access through remote powershell, not remote desktop)

Running Docker version 24.0.2

```
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker> docker --version
Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
```

Currently the dockerd process is running, but in the event log it's listening on API listen on //./pipe/docker_engine_windows

```
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker> Get-EventLog Application -Source docker -Newest 2

   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
  326526 júl. 06 16:06 Information docker                          1 API listen on //./pipe/docker_engine_windows
  326525 júl. 06 16:06 Information docker                          1 Daemon has completed initialization
```

but when I try docker ps (and any other docker command, including our docker builds) I get error:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker> docker ps
error during connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileg
es to connect: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system 
cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't know if it's a significant difference, but it seems the dockerd is listening on `//./pipe/docker_engine_windows` but the docker command expects it on just `//./pipe/docker_engine`

What could be the cause of this? Is this a problem or am I looking in the wrong place?

I am running in an elevated Powershell session, as far as I can tell:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker> whoami /all

USER INFORMATION 
---------------- 

User Name   SID
=========== ============================================
...the user


GROUP INFORMATION 
-----------------

Group Name                                 Type             SID                                           Attributes
========================================== ================ ============================================= ===============================================================
Everyone                                   Well-known group S-1-1-0                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Administrators                     Alias            S-1-5-32-544                                  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Group owner
```

I've tried a few times to restart the services and the processes, switch the engines back and forth, nothing seems to change this. I even managed to restart the computer, but it still behaves this way.

```
.\DockerCli.exe -SwitchLinuxEngine
.\DockerCli.exe -SwitchWindowsEngine
.\DockerCli.exe -switchdaemon
```

All  have similarly nothing effect

```
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker> .\DockerCli.exe -SwitchLinuxEngine
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker> Get-EventLog Application -Source docker -Newest 2

   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
  326526 júl. 06 16:06 Information docker                          1 API listen on //./pipe/docker_engine_windows
  326525 júl. 06 16:06 Information docker                          1 Daemon has completed initialization  

PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker> docker ps
error during connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/contain
ers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: I'm searching for an answer to the same question (and also to another similar one), but this is so far the only information with 'additional value' I was able to find in SO.
My bits of information to this: Windows  11, docker 25.0.2, I've discovered the named pipe //.pipe/docker_engine gets first opened, when the executable com.docker.backend.exe gets executed. This one starts also the Docker Desktop (or requires it) so you end up with a running Docker Desktop application. In my case this is no go as I want a clean and slim execution footprint for my PS scripts.